# Rails configuration with docker-compose remote sdk fails on RubyMine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, docker-compose, ide, rubymine

So I work with RubyMine, and I configured my docker-compose integration like in [this tutorial](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/ruby/using-docker-compose-as-a-remote-interpreter.html), but I have an error when I simply hit the 'run' button:

```
ERROR: Duplicate mount points: [/home/kyrela/railsproject:/railsproject:rw, /home/kyrela/railsproject:/railsproject:rw]
```

A simple `docker-compose up` from the terminal works.

I founded when trying to launch the same command as RubyMine, but removing some arguments, that it was caused by the `docker-compose.override.[number].yml` file generated automatically by RubyMine, based on my configuration. Without it, it works perfectly.

But my configuration is extremely basic :
I only set the IP adress and port, the same as the ones it currently use with a simple `docker-compose up` from the terminal, I set the remote SDK (the one from my container), and the `docker-compose` method to `up`. That's all, I leaved the rest blank or with the default value.

After some research on this error, it's apparently a bug that can be fixed with a simple `docker-compose restart`. It didn't worked for me.

Does someone know how to get rid of this error ?

If some informations are missing, just leave a comment and I will edit my message with the specified informations.

Comment: There's a corresponding thread in RubyMine's community forum so you can check a workaround proposed there: 
https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/4406282722962-Rails-configuration-with-docker-compose-remote-sdk-fails

Comment: Yeah I know that's my question, but thanks